# Proper syntax for application.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

```
Rails 5.1
```

In my Gemflie, I have the following:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

and I want to only use Sass in my application. When I generated the application, I had the following in my application.css file:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/
```

I copied application.css to application.scss and deleted application.css

Would I need to keep these lines in application.scss, or should I replace them with the following lime in application.scss:

```
@import "global";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you should replace **require** statement to **@import**. Below is the sample one,

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap_include';
@import 'dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap';
@import 'jquery-ui/core';
@import 'jquery-ui/theme';
@import 'datepicker';
```

So, that you should be able to use the predefined sass variables in you scss files.